# websphere liberty profile Could not instantiate TransactionManagerLookup caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.ejs.jts.jta.JTSXA

Tags: hibernate, websphere, jta, websphere-liberty

This is taking hell lot of time to resolve . I have a portlet application on was 8.0 , and using hibernate for database transactions .I am trying to migrate it to 8.5.5 liberty profile .we are using hibernate 3.6.9.

persistance.xml looks like this :

```
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class=org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereTransactionManagerLookup
            hibernate.current_session_context_class=jta
            hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion=true
            hibernate.connection.release_mode=auto
        </value>
    </property>
```

Log :

```
00000278 org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory          I Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.ejb.transaction.JoinableCMTTransactionFactory
[8/13/15 0:39:28:182 CDT] 00000278 org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory    I instantiating TransactionManagerLookup: org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereTransactionManagerLookup
[8/13/15 0:39:28:185 CDT] 00000278 org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory    E Could not instantiate TransactionManagerLookup
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain WebSphere TransactionManagerFactory instance
...........
..................
........................

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.ejs.jts.jta.JTSXA
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClassCommonLibraryClassLoaders(AppClassLoader.java:424)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClass(AppClassLoader.java:257)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findOrDelegateLoadClass(AppClassLoader.java:402)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:373)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereTransactionManagerLookup.<init>(WebSphereTransactionManagerLookup.java:67)
    ... 80 more
```

Any suggestions what is happening with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [WebSphereTransactionManagerLookup javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/transaction/WebSphereTransactionManagerLookup.html):

> TransactionManagerLookup strategy for WebSphere (versions 4, 5.0 and
>   5.1)

Try using [WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/transaction/WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks  alot that worked  .. :) , but now i stuck up with another issue :
portlets are using credential vault and context is looking at -->"portletservice/com.ibm.portal.portlet.service.credentialvault.CredentialVaultService" . I tried online how i can set this up in liberty profile , but no luck till now ....  any suggestion on this would be really helpful

Comment: If this answer helped your solve your reported problem, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the answer) and create another question for your new problem.